# Strict Standards: Non-static method in sidebar generator

Tags: plugins, php, oop

I used [this sidebar generator](http://www.getson.info) in my theme functions.php and this plugin work perfectly! No errors. But when I open **define('WP_DEBUG', true)** I got some error. I know that I have to set wp_debug to false on live site. But, I would like to make my theme not to have errors, warning, notice.

I think that some of php guru see this error, he could be able to solve it.

**Error Codes Are Below**

```
    Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method sidebar_generator::init() should not be called statically in /users/hlaporthein/www/venuso/demo/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 470

Strict Standards: Non-static method sidebar_generator::get_sidebars() should not be called statically in /users/hlaporthein/www/venuso/demo/wp-content/themes/venuso/admin/multiple_sidebars.php on line 52

Strict Standards: Non-static method sidebar_generator::name_to_class() should not be called statically in /users/hlaporthein/www/venuso/demo/wp-content/themes/venuso/admin/multiple_sidebars.php on line 57

Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method sidebar_generator::admin_menu() should not be called statically in /users/hlaporthein/www/venuso/demo/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 470

Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method sidebar_generator::admin_print_scripts() should not be called statically in /users/hlaporthein/www/venuso/demo/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 470
```

For you to test easy, I put sidebar generator code in here, you just only need to past that code in functions.php

**Sidebar Generator Code**

```
class sidebar_generator {

    function sidebar_generator(){
        add_action('init',array('sidebar_generator','init'));
        add_action('admin_menu',array('sidebar_generator','admin_menu'));
        add_action('admin_print_scripts', array('sidebar_generator','admin_print_scripts'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_add_sidebar', array('sidebar_generator','add_sidebar') );
        add_action('wp_ajax_remove_sidebar', array('sidebar_generator','remove_sidebar') );

        //edit posts/pages
        add_action('edit_form_advanced', array('sidebar_generator', 'edit_form'));
        add_action('edit_page_form', array('sidebar_generator', 'edit_form'));

        //save posts/pages
        add_action('edit_post', array('sidebar_generator', 'save_form'));
        add_action('publish_post', array('sidebar_generator', 'save_form'));
        add_action('save_post', array('sidebar_generator', 'save_form'));
        add_action('edit_page_form', array('sidebar_generator', 'save_form'));

    }

    function init(){
        //go through each sidebar and register it
        $sidebars = sidebar_generator::get_sidebars();


        if(is_array($sidebars)){
            foreach($sidebars as $sidebar){
                $sidebar_class = sidebar_generator::name_to_class($sidebar);
                register_sidebar(array(
                    'name'=>$sidebar,
                    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                    'after_widget' => '</div>',
                    'before_title' => '<div class="heading"><h3 class="wg-heading">',
                    'after_title' => '</h3></div>',
                ));
            }
        }
    }

    function admin_print_scripts(){
        wp_print_scripts( array( 'sack' ));
        ?>
            <script>
                function add_sidebar( sidebar_name )
                {

                    var mysack = new sack("<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" );    

                    mysack.execute = 1;
                    mysack.method = 'POST';
                    mysack.setVar( "action", "add_sidebar" );
                    mysack.setVar( "sidebar_name", sidebar_name );
                    mysack.encVar( "cookie", document.cookie, false );
                    mysack.onError = function() { alert('Ajax error. Cannot add sidebar' )};
                    mysack.runAJAX();
                    return true;
                }

                function remove_sidebar( sidebar_name,num )
                {

                    var mysack = new sack("<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" );    

                    mysack.execute = 1;
                    mysack.method = 'POST';
                    mysack.setVar( "action", "remove_sidebar" );
                    mysack.setVar( "sidebar_name", sidebar_name );
                    mysack.setVar( "row_number", num );
                    mysack.encVar( "cookie", document.cookie, false );
                    mysack.onError = function() { alert('Ajax error. Cannot add sidebar' )};
                    mysack.runAJAX();
                    //alert('hi!:::'+sidebar_name);
                    return true;
                }
            </script>
        <?php
    }

    function add_sidebar(){
        $sidebars = sidebar_generator::get_sidebars();
        $name = str_replace(array("\n","\r","\t"),'',$_POST['sidebar_name']);
        $id = sidebar_generator::name_to_class($name);
        if(isset($sidebars[$id])){
            die("alert('Sidebar already exists, please use a different name.')");
        }

        $sidebars[$id] = $name;
        sidebar_generator::update_sidebars($sidebars);

        $js = "
            var tbl = document.getElementById('sbg_table');
            var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
            // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
            var iteration = lastRow;
            var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

            // left cell
            var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
            var textNode = document.createTextNode('$name');
            cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

            //middle cell
            var cellLeft = row.insertCell(1);
            var textNode = document.createTextNode('$id');
            cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

            //var cellLeft = row.insertCell(2);
            //var textNode = document.createTextNode('[<a href=\'javascript:void(0);\' onclick=\'return remove_sidebar_link($name);\'>Remove</a>]');
            //cellLeft.appendChild(textNode)

            var cellLeft = row.insertCell(2);
            removeLink = document.createElement('a');
            linkText = document.createTextNode('remove');
            removeLink.setAttribute('onclick', 'remove_sidebar_link(\'$name\')');
            removeLink.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:void(0)');

            removeLink.appendChild(linkText);
            cellLeft.appendChild(removeLink);


        ";


        die( "$js");
    }

    function remove_sidebar(){
        $sidebars = sidebar_generator::get_sidebars();
        $name = str_replace(array("\n","\r","\t"),'',$_POST['sidebar_name']);
        $id = sidebar_generator::name_to_class($name);
        if(!isset($sidebars[$id])){
            die("alert('Sidebar does not exist.')");
        }
        $row_number = $_POST['row_number'];
        unset($sidebars[$id]);
        sidebar_generator::update_sidebars($sidebars);
        $js = "
            var tbl = document.getElementById('sbg_table');
            tbl.deleteRow($row_number)

        ";
        die($js);
    }

    function admin_menu(){
        add_theme_page('Sidebars', 'Sidebars', 'manage_options', 'multiple_sidebars', array('sidebar_generator','admin_page'));

}

    function admin_page(){
        ?>
        <script>
            function remove_sidebar_link(name,num){
                answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove " + name + "?\nThis will remove any widgets you have assigned to this sidebar.");
                if(answer){
                    //alert('AJAX REMOVE');
                    remove_sidebar(name,num);
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
            function add_sidebar_link(){
                var sidebar_name = prompt("Sidebar Name:","");
                //alert(sidebar_name);
                add_sidebar(sidebar_name);
            }
        </script>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Sidebars</h2>
            <br />
            <table class="widefat page" id="sbg_table" style="width:600px;">
                <tr>
                    <th>Sidebar Name</th>
                    <th>CSS class</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $sidebars = sidebar_generator::get_sidebars();
                //$sidebars = array('bob','john','mike','asdf');
                if(is_array($sidebars) && !empty($sidebars)){
                    $cnt=0;
                    foreach($sidebars as $sidebar){
                        $alt = ($cnt%2 == 0 ? 'alternate' : '');
                ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo $alt?>">
                    <td><?php echo $sidebar; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo sidebar_generator::name_to_class($sidebar); ?></td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return remove_sidebar_link('<?php echo $sidebar; ?>',<?php echo $cnt+1; ?>);" title="Remove this sidebar">remove</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                        $cnt++;
                    }
                }else{
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">No Sidebars defined</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </table><br /><br />
            <div class="add_sidebar">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return add_sidebar_link()" title="Add a sidebar" class="button-primary">+ Add New Sidebar</a>

            </div>

        </div>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * for saving the pages/post
    */
    function save_form($post_id){
        if(isset($_POST['sbg_edit'])){
        $is_saving = $_POST['sbg_edit'];
        if(!empty($is_saving)){
            delete_post_meta($post_id, 'sbg_selected_sidebar');
            delete_post_meta($post_id, 'sbg_selected_sidebar_replacement');
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'sbg_selected_sidebar', $_POST['sidebar_generator']);
            add_post_meta($post_id, 'sbg_selected_sidebar_replacement', $_POST['sidebar_generator_replacement']);
        }
        }
    }

    function edit_form(){
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post;
        if (is_object($post_id)) {
            $post_id = $post_id->ID;
        }
        $selected_sidebar = get_post_meta($post_id, 'sbg_selected_sidebar', true);
        if(!is_array($selected_sidebar)){
            $tmp = $selected_sidebar; 
            $selected_sidebar = array(); 
            $selected_sidebar[0] = $tmp;
        }
        $selected_sidebar_replacement = get_post_meta($post_id, 'sbg_selected_sidebar_replacement', true);
        if(!is_array($selected_sidebar_replacement)){
            $tmp = $selected_sidebar_replacement; 
            $selected_sidebar_replacement = array(); 
            $selected_sidebar_replacement[0] = $tmp;
        }
        ?>

    <div id='sbg-sortables' class='meta-box-sortables'>
        <div id="sbg_box" class="postbox " >
            <div class="handlediv" title="Click to toggle"><br /></div><h3 class='hndle'><span>Sidebar</span></h3>
            <div class="inside">
                <div class="sbg_container">
                    <input name="sbg_edit" type="hidden" value="sbg_edit" />

                    <p>Please select the sidebar you would like to display on this page. <strong>Note:</strong> You must first create the sidebar under Appearance > Sidebars.
                    </p>
                    <ul>
                    <?php 
                    global $wp_registered_sidebars;
                    //var_dump($wp_registered_sidebars);        
                        for($i=0;$i<1;$i++){ ?>
                            <li>
                            <select name="sidebar_generator[<?php echo $i?>]" style="display: none;">
                                <option value="0"<?php if($selected_sidebar[$i] == ''){ echo " selected";} ?>>WP Default Sidebar</option>
                            <?php
                            $sidebars = $wp_registered_sidebars;// sidebar_generator::get_sidebars();
                            if(is_array($sidebars) && !empty($sidebars)){
                                foreach($sidebars as $sidebar){
                                    if($selected_sidebar[$i] == $sidebar['name']){
                                        echo "<option value='{$sidebar['name']}' selected>{$sidebar['name']}</option>\n";
                                    }else{
                                        echo "<option value='{$sidebar['name']}'>{$sidebar['name']}</option>\n";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                            </select>
                            <select name="sidebar_generator_replacement[<?php echo $i?>]">
                                <option value="0"<?php if($selected_sidebar_replacement[$i] == ''){ echo " selected";} ?>>None</option>
                            <?php

                            $sidebar_replacements = $wp_registered_sidebars;//sidebar_generator::get_sidebars();
                            if(is_array($sidebar_replacements) && !empty($sidebar_replacements)){
                                foreach($sidebar_replacements as $sidebar){
                                    if($selected_sidebar_replacement[$i] == $sidebar['name']){
                                        echo "<option value='{$sidebar['name']}' selected>{$sidebar['name']}</option>\n";
                                    }else{
                                        echo "<option value='{$sidebar['name']}'>{$sidebar['name']}</option>\n";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                            </select> 

                            </li>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <?php
    }

    /**
     * called by the action get_sidebar. this is what places this into the theme
    */
    function get_sidebar($name="0"){
        if(!is_singular()){
            if($name != "0"){
                dynamic_sidebar($name);
            }else{
                dynamic_sidebar();
            }
            return;//dont do anything
        }
        global $wp_query;
        $post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $selected_sidebar = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sbg_selected_sidebar', true);
        $selected_sidebar_replacement = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sbg_selected_sidebar_replacement', true);
        $did_sidebar = false;
        //this page uses a generated sidebar
        if($selected_sidebar != '' && $selected_sidebar != "0"){
            echo "";
            if(is_array($selected_sidebar) && !empty($selected_sidebar)){
                for($i=0;$i<sizeof($selected_sidebar);$i++){                    

                    if($name == "0" && $selected_sidebar[$i] == "0" &&  $selected_sidebar_replacement[$i] == "0"){
                        //echo "\n\n<!-- [called $name selected {$selected_sidebar[$i]} replacement {$selected_sidebar_replacement[$i]}] -->";
                        dynamic_sidebar();//default behavior
                        $did_sidebar = true;
                        break;
                    }elseif($name == "0" && $selected_sidebar[$i] == "0"){
                        //we are replacing the default sidebar with something
                        //echo "\n\n<!-- [called $name selected {$selected_sidebar[$i]} replacement {$selected_sidebar_replacement[$i]}] -->";
                        dynamic_sidebar($selected_sidebar_replacement[$i]);//default behavior
                        $did_sidebar = true;
                        break;
                    }elseif($selected_sidebar[$i] == $name){
                        //we are replacing this $name
                        //echo "\n\n<!-- [called $name selected {$selected_sidebar[$i]} replacement {$selected_sidebar_replacement[$i]}] -->";
                        $did_sidebar = true;
                        dynamic_sidebar($selected_sidebar_replacement[$i]);//default behavior
                        break;
                    }
                    //echo "<!-- called=$name selected={$selected_sidebar[$i]} replacement={$selected_sidebar_replacement[$i]} -->\n";
                }
            }
            if($did_sidebar == true){
                echo "";
                return;
            }
            //go through without finding any replacements, lets just send them what they asked for
            if($name != "0"){
                dynamic_sidebar($name);
            }else{
                dynamic_sidebar();
            }
            echo "";
            return;         
        }else{
            if($name != "0"){
                dynamic_sidebar($name);
            }else{
                dynamic_sidebar();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * replaces array of sidebar names
    */
    function update_sidebars($sidebar_array){
        $sidebars = update_option('sbg_sidebars',$sidebar_array);
    }   

    /**
     * gets the generated sidebars
    */
    function get_sidebars(){
        $sidebars = get_option('sbg_sidebars');
        return $sidebars;
    }
    function name_to_class($name){
        $class = str_replace(array(' ',',','.','"',"'",'/',"\\",'+','=',')','(','*','&','^','%','$','#','@','!','~','`','<','>','?','[',']','{','}','|',':',),'',$name);
        return $class;
    }

}
$sbg = new sidebar_generator;

function generated_dynamic_sidebar($name='0'){
    sidebar_generator::get_sidebar($name);  
    return true;
}
?>
```

Comment: Syntax errors are off-topic.

Comment: Sorry @cybmeta, I didn't notice that, promise not to happen again :)

Comment: Don't worry. I think [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) is more suitable for your question.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a huge amount you can do about this. Many developers turn off strict errors, as they are pervasive (there are even some in core).

Of course it could be fixed - but then what? It's a plugin, so the next time you update that plugin, your changes will be overwritten.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just wanna know, how it could be soloved because sometimes,I experienced these kind of more errors cause the site death example white screen death, Anyway, Thanks.

Comment: Strict errors wont cause a WSOD. That's fatal errors.